# Three-way join grabs empty rows

Tags: mysql, join

I have a three way join that grabs the correct amount of rows but returns blank values.
The table names and column names are correct.  On the last join, s.int does indeed match SOD.orderID.
I tested it with just the first join and it worked. The [!prefix] is a platform requirement and not affecting the results. It is possible to join two tables to one table?

```
                'SELECT S.name, S.price, SD.store_value AS type, SOD.quantity
                    FROM [!prefix]store as S
                    JOIN [!prefix]storedetail as SD
                    ON S.`int` = SD.storeID
                    JOIN [!prefix]store_orders_details as SOD
                    ON S.`int` = SOD.orderID
                    WHERE S.`int` = ?';
```

Comment: which values are blank? Can you show us some example output?

Comment: Array( [0] => [1] => [2] => )

^That is the result I was getting.  Empty values.

However, now that I tried the solution below, the only blank value is SOD.quantity.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, in the last table does not have adequate data to be merged. Try this:

```
 'SELECT S.name, S.price, SD.store_value AS type, SOD.quantity
                FROM [!prefix]store as S
                JOIN [!prefix]storedetail as SD
                ON S.`int` = SD.storeID
                LEFT JOIN [!prefix]store_orders_details as SOD
                ON S.`int` = SOD.orderID
                WHERE SOD.orderID = ?';
```

Comment: This gave me All the appropriate column titles and values except for SOD.quantity.  SOD.quanitity is blank.  I double-checked the table and there are values there.  I would think that if it had the right column, it would grab the value in the column?